# Getting 404 Not Found for basic spring rest api tutorial - 'hello world'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to create a rest api web application that can be eventually deployed into a container environment. I downloaded quite a few tutorials from spring.io to other websites as well but each time I use the exact repos I get a 404 error for the simple request.

To simplify it further I reduced it to 2 classes in one package:

[project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAgLF.png)

Main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


 @SpringBootApplication
 public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
 }

 }
```

Controller Class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RESTController {

private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
/*
 * REST API Test Methods
 */


@RequestMapping( "/greeting" )
   public String greeting() {
      return "It's working...!";
}
```

And of course the actual request:

```
http://localhost:8080/test_rest_api/greeting

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found


Type Status Report

Message /test_rest_api/greeting

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not 
willing to disclose that one exists.


Apache Tomcat/8.5.43
```

That is running on server by Run As - ; if I select Run as java application and select springboot the following error occurs:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sources must not be empty at 
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:467)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out and it was a stupid mistake. I added the name of the project as part of the domain of the request url.

http://localhost:8080/test_rest_api/greeting

vs

http://localhost:8080/greeting